# chrome.storage.sync.get Alert not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have saved this setting:

```
function save_options() {
  var tbColor = document.getElementById('Color').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    'tbColor': Color
  }, function() {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Settings were saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

and now I'm trying to see the setting via:

`alert(chrome.storage.sync.get({'tbColor'}));`

But I'm getting nothing (no alert shows). I know the overall thing is working because `alert("Hello");` works.

What am I doing wrong with getting these settings? I'm new, so please be easy on me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{'tbColor'}` is invalid syntax, so it errors out first.

Also, `chrome.storage.sync.get` is asynchronous, so you can't use the return value.

You can use:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("tbColor", function(sync) {
  alert(sync.tbColor);
});
```